# Confusion about the text file encoding and how to transform between different encoding method?

Tags: linux, encoding, sed, utf-8, ascii

I had a text file `f.txt` which encoded as UTF-8 as shown below:

```
chengs-MBP:test cheng$ cat f.txt 
Wіnd
like
chengs-MBP:test cheng$ FILE -I f.txt 
f.txt: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

However, this two words in this file `Wind` and `like` are diiferent, as the `like` can be find by `grep` command while `Wind` cannot, it confused me:

```
chengs-MBP:test cheng$ cat f.txt | grep like
like
chengs-MBP:test cheng$ cat f.txt | grep Wind
chengs-MBP:test cheng$
```

And I want to transform this file to `us-ascii` by `iconv` command, but I failed:

```
chengs-MBP:test cheng$ iconv -f UTF-8 -t US-ASCII f.txt > new.txt
conv: f.txt:1:0: cannot convert
```

My goal is to transform this file to a format which all of the words inside this file could be find by `grep` or `sed`... that's all.

Comment: make sure that both formats are in listed in `iconv -l`

Comment: @Arash I tested with `iconv -l`,   Both the UTF-8 and US-ASCII are in list. Can you even copy this two word here: `Wіnd`, `like` to see if you have the same problem?

Comment: This works fine for me:  `printf "Word\nlike\n" | iconv -f UTF-8 -t US-ASCII`

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 is an encoding for the Unicode character set. Some Unicode characters are in look-alike subsets, sometimes collectively called "confusables". So,

```
f.txt | grep "Wind"
```

will look for [LATIN SMALL LETTER I](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0069/index.htm), while

```
f.txt | grep "Wіnd"
```

will look for [CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER BYELORUSSIAN-UKRAINIAN I](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0456/index.htm). You could write it as

```
f.txt | grep "W\xD1\x96nd"
```

Since і is not a member of the ASCII character set, it can't be encoded in ASCII.

If you want to take this further, I suggest that you don't abandon UTF-8 as your text file encoding but you might want to transliterate confusable letters to [Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) or use a search library that deals with transliteration as a feature. `grep` just gives you exactly what you ask for.

Answer (score 0):

In my examples I will use 'i' in word 'Wind' is [CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER BYELORUSSIAN-UKRAINIAN I](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0456/index.htm) in hex `d196`.

For finding out symbol hex representation you can use `xxd` or `hexdump`:

```
$ xxd -g 1 f.txt 
00000000: 57 d1 96 6e 64 0a 6c 69 6b 65 0a                 W..nd.like.

$ hexdump -C f.txt 
00000000  57 d1 96 6e 64 0a 6c 69  6b 65 0a                 |W..nd.like.|
```

As you can see, on the right side, in ASCII section UTF symbols replaced with dots.

Also you can use [Unicode Utitilies](http://billposer.org/Software/unidesc.html).

```
$ uniname f.txt 
character  byte       UTF-32   encoded as     glyph   name
        0          0  000057   57             W      LATIN CAPITAL LETTER W
        1          1  000456   D1 96          і      CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER BYELORUSSIAN-UKRAINIAN I
        2          3  00006E   6E             n      LATIN SMALL LETTER N
        3          4  000064   64             d      LATIN SMALL LETTER D
        4          5  00000A   0A                     LINE FEED (LF)
        5          6  00006C   6C             l      LATIN SMALL LETTER L
        6          7  000069   69             i      LATIN SMALL LETTER I
        7          8  00006B   6B             k      LATIN SMALL LETTER K
        8          9  000065   65             e      LATIN SMALL LETTER E
        9         10  00000A   0A                     LINE FEED (LF)
```

After you find out what symbols in your file are not ASCII, you can replace them in file to ASCII equivalent.

```
$ sed -i 's/\xd1\x96/i/g' f.txt
```